# Replace values with for loop

Tags: for-loop, julia

Suppose I have the following function:

```
function y1(x)
    y = x^(2) - 4
    return y
end
```

Now, I want to evaluate all the values from this sequence: `collect(range(-10,10, 1000))`

I tried this

```
y_1 = zeros(1000);
for x in collect(range(-10, 10, 1000))
   y_1 = y1.(x)
end
```

Note that I use the broadcast operator to apply the function `y1` for every value that takes the iterator. But if I don't use it I get the same result.

But as an answer, I just get 96.0.

How can I refill the `y_1` vector with the for loop, so I get the evaluated values?

The evaluated vector should be of size 1000

Thanks in advance!

### Edit:

I found a way to get to my desired result without the `for loop`:

```
y_1 = y1.(collect(range(-10, 10, 1000)))
```

But I still want to know how can I do it in a loop.

Comment: In a `for` loop you don't need to use `.` broadcasting. `y_1 = Vector{Float64}(undef, 1000); for (i,x) in enumerate(-10:10:1000) y_1[i] = y1(x) ; end`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The broadcast operator *broadcasts* the function over the entire iterator by itself i.e. `y1.(arr)` will

- call `y1` on each of the elements of the array `arr`
- collect the results of all those calls, and
- allocate memory to store those results as an array too

So the following are all equivalent in terms of functionality:

```
julia> arr = range(-4, 5, length = 10) #define a simple range
-4.0:1.0:5.0

julia> y1.(arr)
10-element Vector{Float64}:
 12.0
  5.0
  0.0
 -3.0
 -4.0
 -3.0
  0.0
  5.0
 12.0
 21.0

julia> [y1(x) for x in arr]
10-element Vector{Float64}:
(same values as above)

julia> map(y1, arr)
10-element Vector{Float64}:
(same values as above)

julia> y_1 = zeros(10);

julia> for (i, x) in pairs(arr)
          y_1[i] = y1(x)
       end

julia> y_1
10-element Vector{Float64}:
(same values as above)
```

In practice, there maybe other considerations, including performance, that decides between these and other choices.

---

As an aside, note that very often you *don't* want to `collect` a range in Julia i.e. don't think of `collect` as somehow equivalent to `c()` in R. For many operations, the ranges can be directly used, including for iteration in `for` loops. `collect` should only be necessary in the rare cases where an actual `Vector` is necessary, for eg. a value in the middle of the array needs to be changed for some reason. As a general rule, use the `range` results as they are, until and unless you get an error that requires you to change it.